# How do I implement long-term single sign-on with Firebase and a custom server?

Tags: authentication, firebase, firebase-authentication, token

I have a server-side rendered app that also communicates with Firebase. When a user logs in, the client gets an ID Token from firebase that I then share with my server as described in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens). My server stores the ID Token in a cookie, so that the client will include the token in all requests and my server can check whether the user is logged in.

The problem is that when Firebase refreshes the token after an hour, my server can't verify the token id and redirects them to the login page. Then the client loads, gets the refreshed token from Firebase and stores it in the server cookie, after which requests are authenticated correctly by my server again.

I can make the client refresh the token on every request, but the problem still occurs when the user leaves my site and then returns after one hour.

How can I setup my app so that my server will correctly authenticate users after the firebase token expires?

Comment: what do you excactly mean by 'communicates with Firebase'? What do you excactly do? what kind of server are you running?

Comment: The app uses firebase to store data and files and to authenticate; it uses a custom express server which performs server-side rendering. I'm not sure if the details are necessary... Does that answer your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you need to pro-actively refresh the token before it expires (every hour). When the token is refreshed, you would send it to your server, verify it and set it as the session cookie with the same lifetime as the ID token. You can immediately set it as cookie too from the client (if you are not using http-only cookies).

Your server would receive this cookie with every request, verify it before returning the restricted resource.

I assume you are already aware of this. The problem will occur if the user doesn't visit your site in more than an hour. In that case, your server would consider that user logged out. Here is what you need to do:

User tries to access /myCart which shows their shopping cart when the cookie is expired. Your server detects no cookie and redirects to a temp page:
/redirect?continue=/myCart
On that page you set an onIdTokenChanged or onAuthStateChanged, as soon as it triggers with the latest ID token, you save it as session cookie and redirect to /myCart. Otherwise, you consider the user logged out and redirect to the sign-in page.

Comment: Fantastic! The logic you described in the last paragraph was exactly what I needed. I did make a slight change, though: My cookie's expiration date is set to a year from now (a long time ahead). The server only sends the user to the /redirect page if the user has a cookie containing an expired idToken. If the user has no cookie, then I just redirect from /myCart to /login immediately, no /redirect required. Does that make sense?

Comment: Your logic seems fine, @django09.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to programmatically keep the user "logged in" until he/she either exits the session or logs out - without the token signing him/her out.

I am facing the same problem. I think the best approach is to use Firebase.auth.onAuthStateChanged.

You have that function on the front end client side.

Let's look at the following example:

Suppose the user is on the page www.domain.com/myaccount. He/she is actively on that url. An hour has passed since he/she used the site (and he/she is still actively using it). What you want is to have firebase.auth.onAuthStateChanged in the front end of user side. Once that hour passes, the function is immediately triggered, you can then (inside that function) request a new token from your server and sends it back immediately,  all while the user never knew that the token was switched. (I recommend doing this via AJAX).

I hope this answers your question. If onAuthStateChanged doesnt work with your application for some reason, you can try onIdTokenChanged. See links below.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#onAuthStateChanged

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#onIdTokenChanged